# Interface of function in golang

Tags: go

Consider such function that accepts function as argument:

```
func f(arg func(I)){}
```

where `I` is interface.

Is there any way to pass into above function an argument of signature `func(*T)` where `T` implements `I` interface.

Now when I pass it, I have an error:

```
cannot use (type func(*T)) as type func(I) in argument
```

Here is playground:
https://play.golang.org/p/7vilY4zkEzf

**Use case is the following:**

I write package that has `f(a func(I), b I)` function. Then user will import it as library.

As a next step, user will define a custom type `T` that implements `I` interface and a custom function with signature `func(*T)` . Then user will call library `f` function:

```
f(customFunction, customObject)
```

In turn, package will receive it and create a goroutine:

```
go  customFunction(customObject)
```

The reason why goroutines are created "inside" package is that goroutine orchestration should be hold "under the hood".

Comment: maybe you can use [reflect](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect) to convert that, but this is really depends on your case. If we just know what you are trying to achieve with your problem, we could share better approach

Comment: @xpare thank you, I added the usecase.

Comment: You could use reflection to make this work how you want, but it's going to be very complicated and I'm pretty convinced it's not necessary. Like if the only thing you're doing is calling `go customFunction(customObject)` just make the signature `func()` and expect the caller to pass a closure. Expand even more on your usecase (like full code) and I can help more.

Comment: But the easiest solution is for the client to pass in `func(I)` and type assert to `*T` internally, like the wrapper code in my answer does.

Answer (score 6):

No, the types need to be exact. Your example is especially broken because `I` isn't definitely convertible to `*T`, but it also wouldn't work the other way. If you're *sure* that the type of the `I` being passed to your function is `*T`, you could create wrapper function and pass that instead.

```
func wrapper(i I) {
  t := i.(*T)
  myRealFunc(t)
}
```

Comment: I can't be sure about `T` type because it will be defined in a user space while `myRealFunc` will be library function. I update the question/